How to Resolve "The command 'node' is either misspelled or could not be found" Error on Windows?
If I want to start my React project with npm start I get this error:

The command "node" is either misspelled or
could not be found.

To my project:

node v: v22.11.0
npm v: 10.9.0
react: ^18.3.1

my package.json
{
  "name": "frontend-quizmaster",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}



I tried to reinstall NodeJS.
Also added a new path variable into the system.
I also tried to reinstall npm
  npm uninstall package.json
  npm cache clean -f
  npm install





Check if Node.js is Installed = node -v
Add Node.js to System PATH
Reinstall npm Packages
npm start
thought like this will work

Hey,
node -v works and also I added C:\Program Files\nodejs to  sytsem Path.
I executed npm uninstall package.json after that i installed npm.
-> Nothing changed.
